# random generator won't generate more than 1 password

Tags: c#

I created a random password generator with in a windows form.

The user will select the length of the password and the number of passwords which will be generated in a Richtextbox.

The problem arises when i want to generate more than 1 password.

It does not generate more than 1 password at a time no matter how i do it.

Posting code below.

```
string passwords = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!/@£#$%&[]+``^~*";
    Random pass = new Random();
    string passwordline { get; set; }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        passwordline = "";
        int passwordsNum = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        int passwordLength = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
        int length = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i<passwordsNum; i++)
       {

        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < passwordLength; i2++)
        {
            int randomnumbers = pass.Next(passwords.Length);
            passwordline += passwords[randomnumbers];
            length++;

            if (passwordline.Length == passwordLength)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += passwordline + Environment.NewLine;
            }
           }
          }
         }
```

Comment: And what is the runtime error that you get?

Comment: @dotnetom
I am sorry. I have completely misunderstood what a runtime error is. I corrected it now.

Comment: How do you check that you have generated only one password? Your code is wrong because it doesn't reset the variable after each outer loop but it generates more than one password only concatenated together

Comment: @Steve
dotnetom kindly pointed that out. Thank you.

Comment: Step the code in the debugger your self, that is much faster than having us trying to step the code in our heads. Then you'll note when the code does not work as you expect.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo
Im sorry, i didn't notice that i didn't reset `passwordline`.

Comment: You would have noticed that you did not enter `if (passwordline.Length == passwordLength) {...}` the second time and then if you looked at `passwordline.Length` you would have noticed something weird.
When you have found the "weird" thing in the code the solution is usually not far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it could be that you are not resetting the password to empty with every new run. Try changing code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<passwordsNum; i++)
{
    passwordline = "";
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < passwordLength; i2++)
    {
        //Other code is the same
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a new line between two passwords, now you generate sequences of characters you "concatenate" into one password (and remove some errors):

```
string passwordline = "";
int passwordsNum = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
int passwordLength = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
for (int i = 0; i<passwordsNum; i++) {
    passwordline = "";
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < passwordLength; i2++) {
        int randomnumbers = pass.Next(passwords.Length);
        passwordline += passwords[randomnumbers];
    }
    richTextBox1.Text += passwordline+"\n";
}
```

The code is also more optimized: you use an `if` statement in your `for`-loop, while this code is never executed and simply should be executed at the end of your statement.

Comment: I apologize. I forgot it when publishing the code here.

Comment: Anyway, the code is quite compex compared to the task. And some variables are simply duplicates (like `length` and `i`). You do two checks in each iteration while you can reduce this to one check. The provided code probably runs twice as fast (of course there is probably no noticeable difference).